# Hibernate generic type handling

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have an Entity class which has a generic type field. I want this class to be saved and read from the database. Hibernate can't just take that generic type and save/read it, which is why it asks for custom `@Type` handling. Therefore it expects a `Class<? extends UserType<?>>`. I have been struggling to figure how to properly implement that class. (And I don't know if what I'm trying to do is even possible :D) Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyEntity<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", length = 128)
    private String id;

    // @Type(MyEntityType.class)
    @Column(name = "value")
    private T value;

}
```

Error:
`Property 'my.package.entity.MyEntity.value' has an unbound type and no explicit target entity (resolve this generics usage issue or set an explicit target attribute with '@OneToMany(target=)' or use an explicit '@Type')`

Comment: Found an example on here:
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2342485

which seems to work for the user. He states that you can do something like the following:  

`private Set<? extends Attribute> pointAttributes;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "point", targetEntity=PointAttribute.class)
   public final Set<Attribute> getAttributes() {
      return pointAttributes;
   }`

Comment: Sorry I tried to format my comment with some line breaks but had no luck

Comment: I think the problem is that this guy had a specific type which he could then tell hibernate to use. In my case the value can be anything from Integer to any Object as long as it's Serializable. Maybe it works to have some sort of mapper like Jackson in between that converts the value, regardless of type into JSON and back and saves information on the type within the JSON. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyEntity<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", length = 128)
    private String id;

    @Type(type = "my.package.GeneralizedUserType")
    @Column(name = "value")
    private T value;

}
```

```java
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.*;

public class GeneralizedUserType implements UserType {

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] {Types.JAVA_OBJECT};
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Serializable> returnedClass() {
        return Serializable.class;
    }

    //...
}
```